# On Getting Permission for to Access User's Email

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am using Google APIs PHP client to to access the Google Drive API.

My problem is that I want to get permission to access user email. However the authenticate screen doesn't show the permission I am seeking. It just display "Application would like to ....Have offline access. But when done from the Google API playground, it correctly displays access to users email prompt.

So I think there is something wrong in my code level while creating authenticate url. Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
        $client = new Google_Client();

        $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array( 'curl' => array( CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, ), ));
        $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);
        $client->setAuthConfig($oauth_credentials);

        $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
        $client->setState($this->uri->segment(3));
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is the email address of the current authencated user you can simply go though the google drive api.

[About.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get) method Gets information about the user, the user's Drive, and system capabilities.

```
{
 "user": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
  "photoLink": "xxxx",
  "me": true,
  "permissionId": "xxxx",
  "emailAddress": "xxxx@gmail.com"
 }
}
```

**Side note on scope:**

[Scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) are what tells the user what data you want to access.  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` basically says you want full access to their Google drive account `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails` would request access to their email address.

**Offline access**

'offline' tells the user you want to be able to access their account when they are not using your application.  By adding this you will receive a refresh token which you can save and use at anytime to get a new access token to access a users data.